# Mysql query date between in large table

Tags: mysql, date, count, sum, between

my query is running about 10 seconds and that's unacceptable.

I am looking for a way to improve this speed but i'm out of options.
I have to find the records between now and 30 days back in a table over 12 million rows.

The following query:

```
SELECT DATE(DATE) AS FDATE,
       SUM(VIEW_COUNT) AS COUNT,
       COUNT(IP_ADDRESS) AS CLIENTS
FROM VIEWS
WHERE USERID = 'test'
  AND DATE BETWEEN ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY FDATE DESC
```

I also tried, but the same effect:

```
SELECT DATE(DATE) AS FDATE,
       SUM(VIEW_COUNT) AS COUNT,
       COUNT(IP_ADDRESS) AS CLIENTS
FROM VIEWS
WHERE USERID = 'test'
  AND DATE >= (DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND)
GROUP BY FDATE DESC
```

Comment: Is there a covering index on (userid,date)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using MySQL Indexes for a better performance in decreasing the query execution time.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: "Without an index, MySQL must begin with the first row and then read through the entire table to find the relevant rows. The larger the table, the more this costs. If the table has an index for the columns in question, MySQL can quickly determine the position to seek to in the middle of the data file without having to look at all the data."

Comment: Where do you suggest to use indexes on? This is a stand alone table without refereneces to other tables so only PRIMARY KEY is set to the ID

Comment: As you can see in the text above, now your query reads through all your 12 million rows, with indexes it will determine the dates  and the userid you filtered much faster.

Comment: You don't need to put your indexes on the tables, you can put them on columns too.

Comment: I suggest you to check : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-indexes.html

Comment: So all I need to to in phpmyadmin is select my DATE field and push the index option?

Comment: If that automatically generates you indexes on those columns, you can do that.

Comment: Yes now its running in 1.4sec I guess I have to deal with that. But sure it is an improvement

Comment: Considering the fact that you do filtering on 20 million rows , aggregation and functions it is not that bad.

Comment: An explain plan is the very first thing you should look for when trying to improve performance. There might be better optimization options, just pushing buttons might help but really more detail may lead to better performance. Now you have an index on your date column look at the explain plan (if you don't know to, search)